# Is it possible to fake the country in an iFrame?

Tags: javascript, php, html, iframe, location

There is a website that displays different content depending on which country you are from.
Is it possible in HTML, Javascript or PHP to load the website in an iFrame and fake the country in it so that it is displayed as if I come from a certain other country?
For example: I am from Austria and would like the Germany website to be displayed to me.
Thank you

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't. You can't send informations like an fake IP Adress or something via an IFrame tag to the Website that is getting displayed in it. You can use an VPN service, but this will only work for you.